# How to perevent tinymce add the selection with html tags?

Tags: tinymce

When I copy some text on websites it copies also html tags and after inserting into textarea with tinymce I get the same copy text. For example, If I select a text and copy it with black background I will get it in the textarea too.  I've found the function which strip html tags setContent(html, {format: 'raw'});, but I don't know in which place I have to use it. Who can help to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `paste` plugin with `paste_as_text: true`

```
tinymce.init({ 
  selector: '#mytextarea',
  plugins: 'paste',
  paste_as_text: true,
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/bcu1dcsx/